# Installing an SSD without removing laptop battery

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, battery

Is it generally okay to swap a hard drive to an SSD without removing the laptop battery beforehand? I am using a [Samsung RV520](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/np-rv520).

Comment: Without knowing the make and model of your laptop, the answer is basically… Maybe.

Comment: Please see linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to replace parts or touch internal components while the laptop is powered.

If your laptop has non-removable battery I suggest you try to find its connection and unplug, or at least be extremely careful and avoid touching internal components